# How to make remote websocket connection to nodejs server on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to a nodejs server over a websocket connection but can't get anything to work.

My server.js looks like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io', {
    transports: ['websocket']
})(http);

var server_port = process.env.PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0'

app.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
    console.log('listening on ' + server_ip_address + ":" + server_port);
});
```

My client.js (running on a raspberry pi also running nodejs) is:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://<app-url>',
    {
        reconnect: true,
        transports: ['websocket']
    }
);

socket.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
```

I've also tried on openshift v2 (ports 8000 and 8443) and v3 and no luck there.

If anyone has done this recently please let me know how, thanks!

When debugging the client I get the message:

> engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport error"

and on the server:

> heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"

Comment: Are the client and the server both running on the same machine, accessing through localhost?

Comment: @Marchhill no - the server is hosted on heroku, the client is on a raspberry pi (with internet connectivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's working now. I modified the example in the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets)

I'm not quite sure why my server config doesn't work, but the following does work:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var path = require('path');

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();
var server =  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

var io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Client connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
```

client.js (xShirase was right in saying I needed the correct path here...)

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('https://<url>',
    {reconnect: true, transports : ['websocket'], path: '/socket.io'});

socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a strange bug that happens sometimes, you should be able to get through by adding the path of your client library in the options like so :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://<app-url>:8080',
    {
        reconnect: true,
        transports: ['websocket'],
        path: "/lib/socket.io.js"  //use the relevant path for your file
    }
);
```

But you seem to be using the default options anyway, so you could just do :

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Comment: thanks, I tried using a path - that would be a path to the endpoint where the socket is connecting right? I don't have a hosted js file for the socket.io since I'm running inside node...

Comment: indeed, I overlooked that your client is also on node. You do have a path though, in node_modules, that could be worth a try. I had the exact same issue once, can't remember exactly how I fixed it

Comment: hmm, I tried the node_modules path but it seems to append the path to the GET request when using polling-xhr which seems to be the default...

Comment: I think it tries to establish websocket, and falls back to xhr-polling if it can't. none of the 2 work?